# How to add a top margin before a figure in elsarticle latex template

Tags: margins, subfloats, latex3, elsarticle

I included a figure which contain 3 subfigures.
The problem is that when I put the figure in the top, it doesn't left the top margin, if I put it in the bottom , there is an overlap with the text, it hide the paragraph

My question is how to add the default margin in the top, in this particular page?

```
\begin{figure*}
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 0.35in ]{BM25-fr-snag.png}} 
\hspace*{4.5cm} 
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 0.35in]{LM-french3.png}}
\hspace*{4.5cm} 
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 0.35in]{PL2-snag3.png}}\\

\caption{Recall-Precision curves comparison for the French dataset. }
\label{graph-fr}
\end{figure*}
```

My second problem how to avoid the text overlap in the bottom

Comment: If you are getting overlap, your image files do not honor their bounding boxes.  Try putting an \fbox around each \includegraphics to see how big LaTeX thinks it really is.

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem that should not occur. So the problem originated elsewhere in your code.

Replace your three `.png` images with `example-image` to see if it is related to the images.

You can always  add vertical space, like `\vspace*{<xx>pt}`,  to correct it.

`figure*` in two columns will send the figure to a new page (one column). If you want to keep it with the text, issue a `\onecolumn` before, to start a new page with the figure and text together.

Used the overleaf template from https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/elsevier

This is the normal behavior:

[image: c]

With vertical space added:

[image: a]

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[final,5p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{subfig}% added <<<<<

\usepackage{showframe}% margins
\usepackage{kantlipsum}% dummy text

\journal{Nuclear Physics B}
\begin{document}
    
\begin{frontmatter}
    
\title{Title of Your Manuscript}
\author[inst1]{Author One}
\affiliation[inst1]{organization={Department One},%Department and Organization
            addressline={Address One}, 
            city={City One},
            postcode={00000}, 
            state={State One},
            country={Country One}}
\begin{abstract}
\kant[9]
\end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}

%% main text
\section{Sample Section 1}
\label{sec:sample1}

1. \kant[2-4]
\begin{figure}[hp!] 
    \centering              
    \vspace*{25pt}% added <<<<<
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 0.35in ]{example-image-c}} 
    \hfill 
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 0.35in]{example-image-c}}
    \hfill 
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 0.35in]{example-image-c}}    
    \caption{Recall-Precision curves comparison for the French dataset. }
    \label{graph-fr1}
\end{figure} 

\onecolumn %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\section{Sample  Section 2}

2. \kant[9]

\begin{figure*} % goes to the top of the page
    \centering              
    \vspace*{25pt}% added <<<<<
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 0.35in ]{example-image-a}} 
    \hspace*{4.5cm} 
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 0.35in]{example-image-a}}
    \hspace*{4.5cm} 
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 0.35in]{example-image-a}}
    \caption{Recall-Precision curves comparison for the French dataset. }
    \label{graph-fr2}
\end{figure*} 

\begin{figure*}[hp!]    % after the text
    \centering              
    \vspace*{25pt}% added <<<<<
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 0.35in ]{example-image-b}} 
    \hspace*{4.5cm} 
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 0.35in]{example-image-b}}
    \hspace*{4.5cm} 
    \subfloat{\includegraphics[width = 0.35in]{example-image-b}}
    \caption{Recall-Precision curves comparison for the French dataset. }
    \label{graph-fr3}
\end{figure*} 

\end{document}
```